# What can be said about complexity class of a problem if there exist a pseudo-polynomial verification algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-hard

Let X be a problem for which pseudo-polynomial algorithm time for verification of solution exists. What can be said about complexity of problem X? Can X belong to NP-hard class?

Comment: *Verifying the solution of the problem is known to be weakly NP-hard, i.e. pseudo-polynomial algorithm for verification exists.* NP-hardness is a hardness property. Perhaps you wanted to say that the problem is in nondeterministic pseudopolynomial time?

Comment: As I understand this, for weak NP-hard problems, exact pseudo-polynomial time algorithm exists. Moreover, problem is in NP class if solution can be verified in polynomial time. For problem X, determining correctness of solution is weakly NP-hard, i.e. it is verified using pseudo-polynomial algorithm. This leads me to believe that problem X is certainly not in NP class? But can something other than that be concluded?

Comment: The halting problem is weakly NP-hard.

Comment: "The halting problem is weakly NP-hard." No. It is undecidable.

Comment: It's both weakly NP-hard *and* undecidable.

Comment: But how does this relate to my question?

Comment: I don't understand your question, since you're using terms which don't mean what you think they mean.

Comment: It seems that I do not understand. Only thing I know is that I can verify solution in pseudo-polynomial time. Can anything be concluded from that?

Comment: You can conclude that your problem is in nondeterministic pseudo-polynomial time, which is the complexity class of problems verifiable in pseudo-polynomial time.

Comment: Is this equivalent to NEXPTIME?

Comment: No. It states that when using unary encoding, the problem belongs to NP.

Comment: Consider this: A problem is verifiable in non-deterministic polynomial time (verification is in NP but not necessarily weakly). Then the problem itself is also in NP since a non-deterministic algorithm could guess the right "proof" and verify it in non-deterministic time. I'm not quite sure if and how adding "weakly" would improve this answer

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If we use unary encoding, problem belongs to NP. What if we do not use unary encoding? Can problem be in NP-hard class?

Comment: Comments are not intended for an extended-back-and-forth.  Please [edit] your question to improve it and to fix the issues that people are pointing out in the comments.  Thank you!